# Access Devices On Different Subnet

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, subnet

I have a network set up like the following:
[diagram of my network hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoiTk.png)

Basically, I have a switch that has some devices connected directly to it as well as a router connected to the switch which handles my wireless devices. The problem is that the devices connected to the router can't communicate with the ones connected to the switch, and vice versa. All the devices connected to the router have IPs 192.168.0.x, and with the switch IPs 192.168.1.x. I tried static routing in my router settings to one of the computers with IP 192.168.1.151 connected to the switch with the following settings: [static routing settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owEp1.png) but this does not work and wouldn't be a viable solution to have to individually set every device like this. What is the best way to have communication between these two parts of the network, or do I just need to set up the network differently altogether?

I know questions like these have been asked in the past, so I apologise for redundancy, but I'm really new to this and tried for hours to figure make heads or tails of it and I don't quite understand what I need to do, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mislabeled the box from the ISP and that it's not merely a modem, but actually a home gateway router (with integrated modem) that does NAT and DHCP for your LAN. That is, I assume Computer 1 gets its address from the box labeled "modem".

You need to make the device you labeled "router" stop being a router and simply be an AP. That is, it should not be routing or doing NAT or serving out DHCP leases. It should be a transparent bridge for traffic between the wired LAN and the wireless clients.

Some routers let you disable their NAT/router and DHCP Server functionality, and their WAN Ethernet port becomes the same as a LAN Ethernet port, and the box now only bridges traffic, never routes/NATs it. Other router models don't have a way to disable those things, so you have to use tricks like plugging a LAN port (not the WAN port) into your switch, and telling the DHCP Server feature that its IP address lease pool is zero-length.

Please note that the goal here is to have your whole LAN be a single subnet controlled by the router at the head of the network (the box I think you mislabeled as a modem).

Comment: Yes, you’re right, the ISP modem is also a router; sorry for being unclear. Your workaround for disabling NAT works, and I ended up just disabling DHCP all together.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: this answer does NOT attempt to tell what is the "best" / "right" setup / network structure

Given the diagram in your question, ideally speaking you should add route on `Computer 1`. The route destination should either be the (LAN) IP of `Computer 2` or the subnet address (depending on your needs, obviously), that is:

> 192.168.0.x 255.255.255.255 (192.168.0.x/32)
>
> or
>
> 192.168.0.0/24 255.255.255.0 (192.168.0.0/24)

The gateway/nexthop of the route should be the *WAN* IP of `Router`, which would be a 192.168.1.x.

The route can *instead* be added on `ISP Modem` (which is seemingly a modem+router). It is less ideal (since you unnecessarily involve it in that case and make the pathway on the two directions of the communication "non-parallel") but should work as well. (For the record some router's admin portal only allows you to add a subnet route but not a host route.)

Since presumably `Router` is the "default gateway" on `Computer 2` and has route for `192.168.1.0/24` because that is its WAN subnet, no extra route is needed on `Computer 2` (or `Router`).

The real problem is that `Router` is likely to have a firewall that will prevent traffics that have destination IP within its LAN subnet (or maybe even, any "private* IP or anything other than its WAN IP) from being *forwarded* from "WAN" to "LAN", and there might or might not be an option to turn off such filtering specifically. (An option that allows you to turn off its firewall completely is more likely to be available.)

Another potential problem is that the source NAT on `Router` is implemented in a *stateless* manner, meaning that anything that goes out of the WAN get source NAT'd. (In the *stateful* case, "replying" traffics will not be affected.) In that case you'll need to turn off the source NAT. (Note that this is not the same thing as AP/bridge mode.) There's *a chance* that `ISP Modem` will not source NAT for the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet and `Computer 2` and friends will hence "lose" Internet connection though. It is relatively unlikely that the source NAT is stateless but turning it off will eliminate the "double NAT" problem, so if it works, turning it off is good anyway.